# (number + "Is more than 5") Not running "Concatenation error"

Tags: concatenation, kotlin

I coded this and when I run it, it shows me a message with a problem in "+" between the variable "Number" and the rest of concatenation " is more than 5"
Here is the code

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    print("Enter your Number")
    var number:Int = readLine()!!.toInt()
    if (number>5) {
        println(number + "is more than 5")
    } else if (number==5) {
        println(number + "is equal than 5")

    } else {
        println(number + "is less than 5")
    }

    println("Thank You")
    }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't concatenate a `String` to an `Int` that way, if an `Int` is on the left side of the `+` operator, another number is expected to be on the right hand side (to be more precise, one of `Byte`, `Short`, `Int`, `Long`, `Float`, or `Double`).

It would work the other way around, because `String` does actually have a `+` method that takes an `Int` as its parameter:

```
println("This is a number: " + number)
```

Instead, you can use [string templates](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-types.html#string-templates):

```
println("$number is more than 5")
```

Or if you really dislike those, start with an empty String (not recommended):

```
println("" + number + " is more than 5")
```

Comment: I'd recommend the String template way. When using Kotlin the sooner you get used to its [idioms](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/idioms.html#string-interpolation) the better

Comment: And if you don't want to put any space between number and the next string then you can do this: println("$number"+"-->is more than 5")